# How to measure the time it takes to write data from Apache Kafka to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka

I am using these docker-compose files to connect Apache Kafka and MongoDB with each other:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.2.2
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 35000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.2
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_1://broker:29092,LISTENER_2://broker:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_1://broker:29092,LISTENER_2://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_1:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_2:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: "anonymous"
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 35000
      
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.2.2
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081    
          
  connect:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: connect.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "35000:35000"
      - "8083:8083"
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 35000
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-cluster-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS: 180000
      CONNECT_METADATA_MAX_AGE_MS: 180000
      CONNECT_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"

  mongo1:
    image: mongo:6.0.5
    container_name: mongo1
    ports:
      - "35001:27017"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - connect
    networks:
      - localnet
    restart: always

  mongo1-setup:
    image: mongo:6.0.5
    container_name: mongo1-setup
    volumes: 
      - ./config-replica.js:/config-replica.js
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
    networks:
      - localnet
    entrypoint:
      [
        "bash",
        "-c",
        "sleep 10 && mongosh --host mongo1:27017 config-replica.js && sleep 10",
      ]
    restart: "no"
    
    
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo1
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME: "default"
    networks:
      - localnet
    depends_on:
      - mongo1 

networks:
  localnet:
    attachable: true
```

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.2.5

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt --verbose mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:latest

ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
```

I would like to measure the time between adding data to Apache Kafka and saving the data to MongoDB.How to measure this time in the simplest possible way

I have tried to use JMX, but  I can't find any metrics which allow me to measure this time

Answer (score 0):

You could track consumer lag, then plot that over time, but Kafka doesn't provide any way to query for difference between record timestamps outside of your own custom code, such as using a client Interceptor. Some examples include Confluent monitoring interceptor or Brave-Kafka distributed tracing.